# Creating Google Docs Attachment via API

Tags: basecamp

Is there anyway to create a Google Doc attachment via the API? The documentation doesn't specify if possible and everything I tried didn't work.

Thanks

Edit: Looking at the Basecamp API documentation https://github.com/basecamp/bcx-api/blob/master/sections/attachments.md#get-attachments, Google doc attachments have a different set of fields than uploaded files.

```
Classes.Basecamp.Attachment newAttachment = new Classes.Basecamp.Attachment()
            {
                Name = attachment.Element("name").Value,
                ContentType = attachment.Element("content_type").Value,
                LinkedSource = attachment.Element("linked_source").Value,
                LinkedType = attachment.Element("linked_type").Value,
                LinkUrl = new Uri(attachment.Element("link_url").Value)
            };

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxxx");
            request.ContentType = "application/vnd.google-apps.document";
            request.UserAgent = "xxxx";
            request.Proxy = null;
```

This seems to create a file with no extension.

Can't seem to find another to go about this.

Comment: Could you post what you've tried?

Comment: Edited the question with the code. Sorry for the delay with this.